# JavaScript String split based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have a single variable object value in this format:

```
"Landing Hits: 0Rewards Hits: 0Facebook Posts: 0Twitter Tweets: 0Twitter Autofollows: 0Instagram Photos: 0Instagram Likes: 0Instagram Votes: 0Pinterest Pins: 0Form Submissions: 0Submissions: 0Engagement: 0Views: 0Prints: 0"
```

I need to convert it into:

```
"Landing Hits: 0, Rewards Hits: 0, Facebook Posts: 0, Twitter Tweets: 0, Twitter Autofollows: 0, Instagram Photos: 0, Instagram Likes: 0, Instagram Votes: 0, Pinterest Pins: 0, Form Submissions: 0, Submissions: 0, Engagement: 0, Views: 0, Prints: 0"
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: seems like you should fix the source

Answer (score 4):

You can use [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to search for matches.

```js
var str = "Landing Hits: 0Rewards Hits: 0Facebook Posts: 0Twitter Tweets: 0Twitter Autofollows: 0Instagram Photos: 0Instagram Likes: 0Instagram Votes: 0Pinterest Pins: 0Form Submissions: 0Submissions: 0Engagement: 0Views: 0Prints: 0";

var arr = str.match(/[^:]+\s*:\s*\d+/g); //Find values like `String:Number`

var out = arr.join(", "); //Convert array matches to String

document.write("<pre>" + out + "</pre>"); //Test
```

**Just replace:** If you'll only need is to replace the string, you could also do this:

```js
var str = "Landing Hits: 0Rewards Hits: 0Facebook Posts: 0Twitter Tweets: 0Twitter Autofollows: 0Instagram Photos: 0Instagram Likes: 0Instagram Votes: 0Pinterest Pins: 0Form Submissions: 0Submissions: 0Engagement: 0Views: 0Prints: 0";

var formatted = str.replace(/(\d)(\w)/g, "$1, $2");

document.write(formatted)
```

**Extending into a Object:** This allows you to work the values obtained for another purpose

```js
var str= "Landing Hits: 0Rewards Hits: 0Facebook Posts: 0Twitter Tweets: 0Twitter Autofollows: 0Instagram Photos: 0Instagram Likes: 0Instagram Votes: 0Pinterest Pins: 0Form Submissions: 0Submissions: 0Engagement: 0Views: 0Prints: 0"
, regex = /([^:]+)\s*:\s*(\d+)/g, collection = {}, temp;

while(temp = regex.exec(str)){
  collection[temp[1]] = +temp[2]
}

console.log(collection)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. very nice solution. In Csv file the key and value is coming in same column, now I want to display value in other column relevant to key......any suggestion ??

Comment: You could provide an example in your question?

Comment: I have created csv download functionality. So, when I download in excel file, The key and value is coming in same column . So, just was trying to get value in just second column relevant to key.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var c = "Landing Hits: 0345Rewards Hits: 0Facebook Posts: 0Twitter Tweets: 034534532Twitter Autofollows: 0Instagram Photos: 0Instagram Likes: 0Instagram Votes: 0Pinterest Pins: 0Form Submissions: 0Submissions: 0Engagement: 0Views: 0Prints: 0";
var array = [];
var counter = 0;
var num;
var dup = '';
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  dup += c[i];
  if (c[i] === ':') {
    dup += ' ';
  }
  if (!isNaN(c[i]) && isNaN(c[i + 1]) && c[i] !== ' ') {
    dup += ', ';
  }
}
alert(dup);
```

url (fiddle):https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/kphe5fbL/13/

Answer (score 0):

add the following line in your code

```js
var str = "Landing Hits: 0Rewards Hits: 0Facebook Posts: 0Twitter Tweets: 0Twitter Autofollows: 0Instagram Photos: 0Instagram Likes: 0Instagram Votes: 0Pinterest Pins: 0Form Submissions: 0Submissions: 0Engagement: 0Views: 0Prints: 0";

alert(str.replace(/0|_/g,'0,'));
```

Comment: The value will not always be zero

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Regex`:

```
var str = "Landing Hits: 0Rewards Hits: 0Facebook Posts: 0Twitter Tweets: 0Twitter Autofollows: 0Instagram Photos: 0Instagram Likes: 0Instagram Votes: 0Pinterest Pins: 0Form Submissions: 0Submissions: 0Engagement: 0Views: 0Prints: 0";
var newStr = str.split(0).join('0, ').slice(0, -2);
```